# Access 2010 Web Database OpenForm Action

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am designing a web database using Access 2010

I have put a macro which uses the openform action

The Window Mode for this Action is "Dialog". in the dropdown this is the only option which is available for this setting.

when the form opens up, i can see that it is very small and its size is fixed.

I want to set the initial size of the form, or atleast make it resizeable so that uses can enter data properly in the newly opened form

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but found this:
http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=G78tE7JjgDcC&pg=PA775&lpg=PA775&dq=access+2010+macro+set+window%2Bmode&source=bl&ots=bvmf2qN0fL&sig=gcAysal_0g1jJ3gOJP2c5WGVbKE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yMkeUI-KJaWG0AXNu4GoAw&ved=0CE0Q6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=access%202010%20macro%20set%20window%2Bmode&f=false
(bottom of page 775)

Shows that Access 2010 macros are web based and only open forms in dialogue mode, not tabbed mode as in access. This does not show any other way around the problem! But I'm still looking.